# Tkinter - disabling individual optionmenus (created with for loop)once clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, disable

I've used a for loop to create several optionmenus (drop downs.)

Example -

For i in range (10):

```
Drop = optionmenu(root, var, *list)
Drop.grid(row = i, column =1)
```

My question is - is it possible to call a function that can disable each drop down independently AFTER AN OPTION FROM THE DROPDOWN HAS BEEN  SELECTED?

I've tried several attempts at this already and the best I can do is to get the very last drop-down to disable OR to disable them all at once.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes., you can, but not looping.

Comment: Is it possible to save and recall the disabled states of widgets? @toyota